# Travel Stack Exchange + Wikivoyage mashup ideas?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tools, wikivoyage

Since we and Wikivoyage both have the same content licences and since I have experience hacking code for both the Stack Exchange and MediaWiki APIs and the Wikimedia toolserver, I'm thinking that there must be some cool features I could add to integrate the two sites a bit.

Does anyone have any ideas?

(If your idea is going to be about any site or service or API other than these two sites, then please ask in a new question - I don't have experience with mapping sites for instance.)

---

And if anyone else wants to join in you're more than welcome!

Answer (score 9):

```
if (tagwiki)
 let it be
else
 populate with excerpt from Wikivoyage
```

Comment: There's a good few ways to title a place in Wikivoyage, and a good few place names that occur multiple times. Also actually add a tag wiki or display stuff from Wikivoyage instead of displaying a blank wiki? The latter seems doable (-:

Answer (score 9):

In no particular order:

- Easy way to link to Wikivoyage (WV). Basically, specially formatted links which are easy to type without having to go to Wikivoyage and copy-paste the URL. For example, similar syntax to the `[tag:foo]` formatting, and the links can be styled differently as well.
- Integrate with WV as their "official" Q&A platform. I think there's potential for both sites together to become one-stop place for everything travel-related.

  - WV could be the first stop for users travelling to X, and if there's a question unanswered by WV, then they could be furthered to Travel-SE to ask their question.
  - As a bonus, some related questions can appear on the WV page, using tags as filter (not sure if that is at all possible with SE API).
  - Allow WV users to create Travel-SE accounts via OpenID (not sure if that's currently done, or if it's possible on WV's end).

Comment: Agree with that. Imho, the big potential is not a tool or anything similar, but collaboration.

Comment: All of your suggestions are good but would requre either changes to the Stack Exchange engine itself, or official policies from the Stack Exchange people, or both. I recommend moving this from an answer here to a proposal as its own question either here or over in the big network-wide meta.SO (or meta.SE if they've branched them yet).

Comment: @hippietrail: Yeah, that's probably a good idea, but I'll wait until we're out of beta. Then we can have a more thorough discussion among Travel-SE users and after that seek SE assistance.

Comment: +1 great ideas (even if difficult). By the way, I believe you meant Wikivoyage (WV) ?